# Android list view order show wrong

Tags: android, android-listview, sqlite

I've to get record from phone database by these query

```
 SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE Id IN (Select id FROM tableName order by Id desc LIMIT 3)      order by Id asc
```

It's worked in sqlite manager but when i try it in android phone the new record shows at the top of the list

Please help me on these problem. i'm new in android.

Comment: please show your list adapter implementation, this is where we can add a list reversal

Comment: I have resolved the issue by using the cursor to read from last record to first. Thanks to avalancha by your comment i think on that and i got a solution.